# Type error: Wrong object type. - Basic prolog error

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to learn prolog and i bumpt in this error which, i don't know why i get it so i am asking for your help.

code(TPROLOG#86):

```
trace 

domains
    item = integer
    intList = item*

predicates
    member(item,intList)

clauses
    member(elm,[elm|_]).

    member(elm,[_|T]):-  %%%  ***ELM is seen as wrong type, why?***
        member(item,[T]).

goal
    member(5,[1,2,3,4,5])
```

Any advice or hint is welcomed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing variables and atoms. Atoms start with a lower case letter, whereas variables start with an upper case letter.

Also, your `member/2` definition seems wrong. It should read:

```
clauses
    member(Elm,[Elm|_]).
    member(Elm,[_|T]):-  
        member(Elm,T).
```

First clause matches the element with the head of the second list. Second clause skips the head of the second list and recursively calls `member/2` to find another match in the tail of the list.